# vb.net control's events only when user clicks

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am looking for an event which is fired when the user changes the value of a dropdownlist or changes the text in a textbox.

I do NOT want to have the event fired when my code behind fills these controls.

Is there a standard event handler for that or do I have to use variables like UserFormInitialized=true?

Dropdownlist.SelectedIndexChanged or Textbox.Textchanged is also fired from code behind. The click event does not fit because it is not sure that the user changes the data in the textbox after clicking it.

Comment: If you don't want the events to "fire" as a result of you setting them via code, then setting up a boolean flag that gets checked in those events is a perfectly reasonable approach; especially since you may want this to occur at points other than just form initialization.

Comment: Look at the `Click` events instead of `Change` events

Comment: Thank you djv, but as described in my question "The click event does not fit because it is not sure that the user changes the data in the textbox after clicking it."